# How do I add migrations to existing project

Tags: sequelize.js

I understand you can use sequelize init to create the migrations folder but I pulled this repo to learn about crud: [Crud with sequelize](https://github.com/lorenseanstewart/sequelize-crud-101)

I want to add migrations to this project. How would I do that?